# Транзакции SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, транзакции

Насколько я понял смысла в обычном добавлении вообще нет? Для этого и нужны транзакции? Или у чего то есть свои плюсы и минусы?

Comment: Если рассматривать именно sqlite, то эта СУБД каждую вставку (insert) оборачивает в транзацию. Поэтому вставки по одной работают очень медленно. А если оборачивать вставки в одну общую транзакцию вручную, то скорость их выполнения на три порядка больше. Я как-то для другой темы [пример](https://pastebin.com/KfFKnTB9) кода набросал (на C#, но не суть): сто тысяч инсёртов чуть более секунды с HDD, 0,7 сек с SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Хм. Давайте определимся сначала, транзакция позволяет атомарно выполнять последовательность операций aut Caesar, aut nihil - вся последовательность либо будет выполнена, либо откатится.

Если у вас весь процесс - это вставка всего одной записи (добавление новости, к примеру), то транзакции не нужны.

Типичный пример, когда описывают необходимость транзакций - это банковский перевод. У вас есть два счёта. Вы хотите перевести деньги с одного счёта на другой:

1. Снять деньги с одного счёта.
2. Зачислить на другой счёт.

Если это делать без транзакции, то, к примеру, если после выполнения первой операции что-то случится (отключат электричество, сеть упадёт и т.п.), то деньги снимутся, но второму клиенту их не зачислят.

Если это делать транзакцией, то такого не произойдёт. Либо выполнятся обе операции, либо, если произойдёт ЧП после первой операции, оная откатится.